# Performing SDNA 3d network analysis with ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, sdna

[image]

I am trying to use SDNA commands to run the 3d network analysis on the ArcScene Shape file. I can view the shape file as 3d, however when I run the SDNA Prepare command, the below error message comes.

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

The same process works perfectly fine for 2d files in ArcMap.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures.

Comment: The access violation suggests this is a bug in sDNA Prepare, possibly triggered by something unique to your shapefile. If you are able to share the shapefile (here or to sdna@cardiff.ac.uk) I will be able to investigate. In the meantime you could try switching off the isolated systems check in sDNA prepare and see whether the problem still occurs?

Comment: On PolyGeo's comment, for future reference - ArcGIS doesn't make it obvious but you can copy all messages as text by right-clicking the 'messages' line in the results window

Comment: Hi Bob, the command worked when I switched off the isolated systems check:); but in this case it only generated a .csv file as output, no shape file like the 2d process. I will email you the shape file for reference and you could probably take a look.

Comment: Noted on the text format for error messages, will keep in mind for future queries.